# Setting up wildcard DNS for lots of domains

Tags: domain-name-system, bind, dns-hosting, dyndns

I want a nameserver that points any names at the same IP. This way I can rapidly change a bunch of domains name servers to ns1.ABC.com and ns2.ABC.com and have all those domains be pointed to the same IP (which will then be managed by wordpress multi user).

Any idea on how to do this - either an outsourced DNS provider that supports this or how I would do it with Bind?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

BIND should be able to do this by 'fooling' it into thinking it is authoratative for a higher level zone, such as `com`, for example.

```
zone "com" { type master; file "/etc/bind/files/catch_all.db"; };
```

Then, in your `catch_all.db` file:

```
$TTL 300
@               IN SOA  ns1.domain.example. hostmaster.domain.example. (
                            2012020301 ; serial
                            6H ; refresh
                            1H ; retry
                            2W ; expire
                            6H ; minimum
                        )
                IN      NS      ns1.domain.example.
                IN      NS      ns2.domain.example.
*               IN      MX      10 mail.domain.example.
mail            IN      A       10.0.0.2 ; Your mail server's IP.
*                       A       10.0.0.1 ; The IP you want all domains to resolve to.
```

This will apply to any request for a domain in the `com` zone that hits your server.  You can do the same for other top-level zones as well:

```
zone "net" { type master; file "/etc/bind/files/catch_all.db"; };
zone "org" { type master; file "/etc/bind/files/catch_all.db"; };
zone "co.uk" { type master; file "/etc/bind/files/catch_all.db"; };
```